# Python struct.pack()/calcsize()

Tags: python, struct, pack

I want to pack a byte followed by a long. My buffer can only contain 9 elements. Why can't I pack them into the buffer?

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> calcsize('qB')
9
>>> calcsize('Bq')
12
```

It returns differently. Why is this?

I'm using Python 2.7.3 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, `struct.calcsize` assumes 3 bytes of padding after the byte so that the long long can begin on a 4-byte boundary.

If you specify no padding, you'll see they are equivalent:

```
>>> calcsize ('Bq')
12
>>> calcsize('=Bq')
9
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you, it's seems you're right. I didn't realize that Python couldn't use native sizes by default.

Comment: `struct` uses native size, byte order, and alignment unless you specify an explicit byte order, in which case standard size and no alignment is used. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) for details.